# Flutter - VoidCallback content is not executing

Tags: flutter

I've created the following custome widget:

```
class MainButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  String _text = "";
  TextTheme _textTheme = new TextTheme();
  IconData _icon = null;
  VoidCallback _onPressed;

  MainButtonWidget(String text, TextTheme textTheme, IconData icon, VoidCallback onPressed){
    _text = text;
    _textTheme = textTheme;
    _icon = icon;
    _onPressed = onPressed;
  }

  void setText(String text){
    _text = text;
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Container(
    child: new RaisedButton(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          Dimens.edgeMainButtonLRB, Dimens.edgeMainButtonT,
          Dimens.edgeMainButtonLRB, Dimens.edgeMainButtonLRB),
      shape: new CircleBorder(side: new BorderSide(
          color: ColorRes.whiteTranslucent2,
          width: Dimens.widthSmallButtonHome)),
      onPressed: (){
        debugPrint("mainButtonWidget before _onPressed");
        _onPressed;
        debugPrint("mainButtonWidget after _onPressed");
        },
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Icon(
            _icon,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          new Text(_text,
            style: _textTheme.button.copyWith(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),)
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

}

Here is how I created an object of type MainButtonWidget:

```
Widget mapMainBtn = new MainButtonWidget('Map', textTheme, Icons.location_on, ()=> debugPrint("mapMainBtn -> onPressed called"));
```

When pressing on the button seems that the content of the VoidCallback is not executing.

In the log the following messages are shown:
I/flutter (21436): mainButtonWidget before _onPressed
I/flutter (21436): mainButtonWidget after _onPressed

I expected to see 'mapMainBtn -> onPressed called' between the above messages.

Answer (score 8):

To call it `()` is required

```
_onPressed();
```

Comment: Wow, fantastic. Played with this for 30 minutes...

Comment: @günter-zöchbauer what is the difference between calling {         onPressed:() {_onPressed()}     }  and {    onPressed: _onPressed;     }

Comment: The first creates an inline function (closure) that calls `_onPressed` when the closure is called itself. The 2nd just passes the `_onPressed` to be called. In the former the closure is redundant.
Usually the later is necessary when the number, the types, or the order of the parameters doesn't exactly match. For example `{ onPressed: () { _onPressed('my button'); }`. If you need a string or any other parameter passed, then `_onPressed` can not be passed directly to `onPressed:` because the compiler complains. Then use a closure instead.

Answer (score 0):

_onPressed() is called. 
Please see the code bellow:

```
`onPressed: (){
 debugPrint("mainButtonWidget before _onPressed");
    _onPressed;
    debugPrint("mainButtonWidget after _onPressed");
}`
```

Comment: no, it isn't, because `()` are missing. See my answer

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I thought that is enough to write _onPressed without '()'.

Comment: Without it is just a reference to the function, for example to pass it around to be called from somewhere else, but the invocation is caused by `()`