# Trying to build Listview but I can't add any method to the Expansion tile

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, expandablelistview, expansion-tile

I have the following code to build a listview from local JSON file and it works perfectly fine. However, when I try to add a method such as `onTap: (){}` to the `ExpansionTile` in the `_buildList` Widget I got the following error

> `Error: No named parameter with the name 'onTap'. onTap: (){}, ^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_tile.dart:51:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match. const ExpansionTile({ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^`

The code in `Main.dart` is

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'datamodel.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}


class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

    Future<List<Menu>> ReadJsonData() async {
    //read json file
    final jsondata = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data0.json');
    //decode json data as list
    final list = json.decode(jsondata) as List<dynamic>;
    //map json and initialize using Model
    return list.map((e) => Menu.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home:Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('My Title'),
            ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: ReadJsonData(),
          builder: (context,data){
            if(data.hasError){
              return Center(child: Text("${data.error}"));
            }else if(data.hasData){
              var items =data.data as List<Menu>;
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    _buildList(items[index]),
              );
            }else{
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
          },
        )
    )
    );
  }

    Widget _buildList(Menu list) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      leading: Icon(list.icon),
      // line causing error
      onTap: (){},
      title: Text(
        list.name!,// I added !
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: list.font?.toDouble(), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      children: list.subMenu!.map(_buildList).toList(),// I added !
    );
  }
}
```

So is there any way to add the Method for each Expansion tile?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello. I guess you need to use "VoidCallback".

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean? I am new to dart and flutter so could you help with an example? thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894273/how-to-execute-the-voidcallback-in-flutter)

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues Thank you. I am working on this link and other links that describe the VoidCallback but still have errors. Let me try again to figure out what I am missing.

Comment: I tried this website  [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-widget-communication ) also but have no clue about what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ExpansionTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) does not have an `onTap` property. This is because it has a default behaviour on tapping, expands or collapses.

If you'd like to execute some specific logic on expanded or collapsed, you can use [`onExpansionChanged`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile/onExpansionChanged.html):

```
return ExpansionTile(
  onExpansionChanged: (bool expanded) {
    // do what you want
  },
);
```