# Hide Floating Message in Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, mobile

I've been tasked to remove a floating message on Flutter. I want to remove it when I click on the Cancel Button but the problem is, the code for the floating message is found on another file while the code for the Button is also found in another File. How do I do it so that when I click on the Cancel Button (found on File 2) will hide the Floating Message?

I'll provide both the code for the Floating Message and the Cancel Button below:

**file1.dart (where the Floating Message Code is found)**

```
 widget.isNewOrder
                    ? FloatingMessageWidget(
                        color: Color(0xFFEC5D77).withOpacity(0.6),
                        height: 44,
                        width: 290,
                        text: 'Click acknowledge before preparing.',
                      )
                    : Container(),
```

**file2.dart (where the Cancel Button Code is found)**

```
 onPressed: widget.isConfirmBtnEnabled
                ? () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    int _selectedIndex = widget.selectedIndex;
                    String _cancelReason =
                        (_selectedIndex >= nonOtherFromIndex &&
                                _selectedIndex <= nonOtherToIndex)
                            ? _cancelOptions[_selectedIndex]
                            : widget.textInputValue;

                    widget.orderDetailBloc?.markStoreOrderAsCanceled(
                        widget.storeOrderId, _cancelReason);
                  }
                : null,
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you so much.

Edit: I can't seem to understand how to use the VoidCallback in this code even after reading the document, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try wraping the `onPressed` of File2 inside `setState`.

```
onPressed: widget.isConfirmBtnEnabled
                ? () {
                    setState((){
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    int _selectedIndex = widget.selectedIndex;
                    String _cancelReason =
                        (_selectedIndex >= nonOtherFromIndex &&
                                _selectedIndex <= nonOtherToIndex)
                            ? _cancelOptions[_selectedIndex]
                            : widget.textInputValue;

                    widget.orderDetailBloc?.markStoreOrderAsCanceled(
                        widget.storeOrderId, _cancelReason);
                    });
                  }
                : null,
```

Comment: Hi there, the message is still there even after wrapping the onPressed with setState. I also asked ChatGPT and it told me to use "final VoidCallback" and call it on File 2, but I don't know how to do that. Any inputs?

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894273/how-to-execute-the-voidcallback-in-flutter

Comment: Thanks! I'll read about that and comeback when I need more help. Cheers.